# Is it possible to use a string variable to reference an element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, variables, reference

Here's the quick version of the code as it stands right now:

```
function foo(attributeName, someJSObj, key, newValue)
{
    someJSObj[key].attributeName = newValue;
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, since it just creates a new element called attributeName.  Is there an easy way to dereference the attributeName into the string that represents some existing attribute on someJSObj?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the bracket notation for `attributeName` as well:

```
function foo(attributeName, someJSObj, key, newValue)
{
    someJSObj[key][attributeName] = newValue;
}
```

Now the value of `attributeName` is used as identifier instead of the identifier `attributeName` itself.

Comment: This works!  Didn't know that properties could be referenced ala second order arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you could use ECMAScript

```
function foo(attributeName, someJSObj, key, newValue)
{
    someJSObj[key][attributeName] = newValue;
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try someJSObj[key].setAttribute(attributeName, newValue)